# React V6 - How to pass an object from a class component to another (and not to functional component)

Tags: reactjs, class, object, components, router

I am trying to pass an object to a class component via the router.
The browser doesn't display any error, but I don't know how reach the object
It's worked when I user the v5, but not with the v6
All the answers available on the subject are for the case you use functional component

```
<Link to={`myPath`} state={{ myObject }}>
....
</Link>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are passing the state object is incorrect. Please try like this

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/myPath",
    state: myObject
  }}
/>
....
</Link>
```

for more information refer :

> https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Link

Comment: Yes thank you it is works on react v5. I was on v6, but after downgrading to react-router-dom to v5 and changing my code by yours, It's working. Thank you!